# Expresion regular Powershell en comando netsh wlan show profiles

Tags: powershell, regular, expresion

Estoy creando un script en PowerShell que crea un fichero con nombre y clave de todas las redes Wifi a las que se ha conectado el equipo. Mi idea es crear otro que importe esas claves. Muy util para cuando formateas un equipo.

Se que en Github hay varios (ninguno me ha funcionado) y se que hay aplicaciones (no me fio..)

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
# Obtener la lista de redes WiFi a las que se ha conectado el sistema
$wifiNetworks = (netsh wlan show profiles) -match 'Perfil de todos los usuarios   *: *([^\r\n]*)'


# Crear un archivo de texto para guardar la información
$filePath = "$env:C:\wifi_networks.txt"
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $filePath -Force

# Recorrer la lista de redes WiFi y exportar su nombre y clave
foreach ($wifiNetwork in $wifiNetworks)

{
    $wifiNetwork = $wifiNetwork.Trim()
    # Mostrar el valor de la variable $wifiNetwork en la consola
    Write-Host "El nombre de la red WiFi es: $wifiNetwork"


    # Obtener la contraseña de la red WiFi
    $wifiPassword = netsh wlan show profile name="$wifiNetwork" key=clear | Select-String 'Contenido de la clave'

    # Guardar la información en el archivo de texto
    Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value "Network: $wifiNetwork`nPassword: $wifiPassword"
}

# Mostrar un mensaje de confirmación
Write-Host "La información de las redes WiFi se ha exportado exitosamente a $filePath"
Pause
```

Lo siento si no estoy poniendo el codigo bien. Todavia no se muy bien como se pone.
Se que la linea uno

```
$wifiNetworks = (netsh wlan show profiles) -match 'Perfil de todos los usuarios   *: *([^\r\n]*)'
```

Esta mal. Pero no se como pinerlo bien. Lo que quiero es que solo almacene el nombre de la red wifi y no toda la frase :(.

¿Alguien sabria decirme que estoy haciendo mal? No se me da especialmente,lo se.

Muchas g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código esta bien pero tiene problemas dentro de el ciclo foreach, intenta dejando el ciclo así:

```
foreach ($wifiNetwork in $wifiNetworks){
     $wifiNetwork = $wifiNetwork.split(":")[1].Trim()
     # Mostrar el valor de la variable $wifiNetwork en la consola
     Write-Host "El nombre de la red WiFi es: $wifiNetwork"


     # Obtener la contraseña de la red WiFi
     $wifiPassword = netsh wlan show profile name="$wifiNetwork" key=clear | Select-String 'Contenido de la clave'

     $wifiPassword="$wifiPassword".split(":")[1].Trim()
     
     # Guardar la información en el archivo de texto
     Add-Content -Path $filePath -Value "Network: $wifiNetwork`nPassword: $wifiPassword"
 }
```

Puede que se vea raro el Trim al final, pero al usar Trim solo se quitan los espacios extras, ya sea duplicados o al inicio o al final de la frase o palabra, no los espacios entre palabras, símbolos, letras, etc. Por lo qu el caso de **" Palabra : frase uno"** el espacio entre los 2 puntos y frase no desaparece, por lo que al usar split después queda con un espacio **" frase uno"** y con ese espacio toma ese nombre como una wifi que no tienes.

**Aporte previo**

Creo que no es lo que estas buscando, pero puede ser de utilidad.
Yo para conectar wifi en equipos, primero exporto la red wifi y luego puedo usar ese archivo indefinidamente.

Para exportar una wifi uso el comando:

```
netsh wlan export profile "nombreDeWifi"
```

Eso te guardara un archivo con el nombre Wi-Fi-nombreDeWifi.xml en el directorio que te encuentres en la Powershell, lo mas seguro es que sea en la carpeta de tu usuario, este paso solo se realiza la primera vez ya que teniendo el archivo lo puedes usar cuanto quieras.

También puedes exportar todos los perfiles con el mismo comando, pero sin especificar un nombre de red, osea:

```
netsh wlan export profile
```

Después de eso para importar el archivo, lo copio al otro equipo, lo ubico en la ruta que prefiera y lo importo.

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="C:\ruta\Wi-Fi-nombreDeWifi.xml"
```

Si quieres que se conecte inmediatamente puedes usar:

```
netsh wlan connect name="nombreDeWifi"
```

Como información adicional, si quieres que el archivo sea visible la contraseña y no este protegida basta con añadir **key=clear** al comando
Quedando:

```
netsh wlan export profile "nombreDeWifi" key=clear
```

Con eso el archivo pasara de esto:

```
<protected>true</protected>
<keyMaterial>01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB010000005DE18ADE0201654DAB617B9C1160EDE0000000000200000000106600000001000020000000C1B62C38E19B8D405DF791911F48C49ACCDA713341D84C2C048D7C986EE72B77000000000E80000000020000200000006E5968B43EFB16C4372207F7864D9763C84A949FFC764C37A4012F3D7AB1000000022CA60F848B5C92746A7B8E7912B22D940000000F0ECA146AA042AE4D21E006DE08356A1B4F997843E3B8994412073FF703486FAA81F2F24BFC854A24A78EDA20717221FD90FD68EE59B71241F2</keyMaterial>
```

A esto:

```
<protected>false</protected>
<keyMaterial>clave123</keyMaterial>
```

Comment: Y si editas la otra respuesta y añades todo lo que crees que el OP puede mejorar en su código? :)

Comment: una sola respuesta!!! si ya tenias una, por favor, edita esa ;)

Comment: No he podido probar la ultima solucion que me diste, pero si la otra forma de hacerlo. Me gusto. Me resulto util :D.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del foreach, puede hacer algo como así

```
$wifiNetworkArr = $wifiNetwork.Trim().Split(":")
# Mostrar el valor de la variable $wifiNetwork en la consola
Write-Host "El nombre de la red WiFi es:" . $wifiNetworkArr[1]
$wifiNetwork = $wifiNetworkArr[1]
```

$wifiNetworkArr[1] es el segundo string que resulta del split().

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado y no me ha funcionado. Seguire probando.